# How do I switch between "Source", "Preview" and "Source and preview" tabs in Eclipse

Tags: xml, eclipse, preview, editing

I  have to switch between "Source" and "Preview" tabs a lot while editing xml files in Eclipse. So trying to find a way to do this quickly without leaving the keyboard. Does anybody know of any? I am talking two, max three, key stroke long shortcuts. Well, I guess there should be a way to customize the key combinations. TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `Preferences Dialog > General > Keys` and find `Previous/Next Sub-Tab` command.

If you are in Windows, it is bound to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PageDown</kbd>.

In MacOSX(Mac Book Air), it is bound to <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow up</kbd> and <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow down</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd> is "Next Page" and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd> is "Previous Page". Those work for sure with the Android graphical editor and its two tabs.

Please be aware that at least on Ubuntu the first combination is already an Ubuntu hotkey and therefore does not work by default (you have to change it to another combination).